# OraOLEDB : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Receiving a SQL Error when running this subquery in my datablock

I'm trying to return the employees former position at their last employer

Here is my query:

```
(select
(case
WHEN

(select
distinct
'x'
from aprehis a
where
donor.pidm = a.aprehis_pidm
and a.aprehis_empr_pidm is null
and trunc(a.aprehis_to_date) =

(select max(trunc(aprehis_to_date))
from aprehis b
where b.aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
and trunc (b.aprehis_to_date) is not null))= 'x'
THEN
(select distinct (aprehis_empl_position)
from aprehis where
aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
and aprehis_empr_name =

(select max(aprehis_empr_name)
from aprehis d
where d.aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
and trunc(d.aprehis_to_date) =

(select max(trunc(aprehis_to_date))
from aprehis c
where c.aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
and trunc (c.aprehis_to_date) is not null)))

ELSE

 (select distinct (aprehis_empl_position)
 from aprehis where aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
 and aprehis_empr_name =
 (select spriden_last_name
 from spriden
  where spriden_change_ind is null
  and spriden_pidm =

 (select max(aprehis_empr_pidm) from aprehis e
  where e.aprehis_pidm = donor.pidm
  and e.aprehis_empr_pidm is not null
   and trunc(e.aprehis_to_date)=(select max(trunc(aprehis_to_date))
  from aprehis b
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: This isn't your full query.  As far as I can see there are five (!) unclosed parentheses.  Some suggestions: (1) edit the question to include your full query, (2) indent the query to make the subquery structure more obvious, (3) provide us with some sample data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The full query is too long to insert...this is just one of the fields I need returned.

Comment: If the full query is too long to insert, how do we know that the problem isn't in the part of the query you haven't shared with us?

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the following line, in two different places:
    select distinct (aprehis_empl_position)

to:
    select MAX (aprehis_empl_position)